Access to Linkedin Messages API - Is there a solution?
I have read a lot of posts about access to messaging api such as this one:
Linkedin Messaging API access
However, none of them actually provide any clear direction on how to request access to the messages api, and LinkedIn does not have direct support for the API. I already opened up a ticket to the regular LinkedIn support and they directed me to here, so I am kind of in a non-breaking cycle of trying to figure this out, if that makes sense.
I have also created an app on https://developer.linkedin.com/, however, none of the API's that one can request access to contain the Messages API endpoints.
Has anybody even ever gotten access to the Messages API? If yes, how?
